# Reset count of group after pandas dataframe concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing data processing and I have a problem figuring out how to reset groups counter after concatenating pandas dataframes. Here is an example below to illustrate my problem:

For example I have two dataframes:

```
   Counter       Value
0        1           3
1        1           4
2        1           2
3        2           4
4        2          10
```

```
   Counter       Value
0        1           8
1        1          10
2        2           2
3        2           4
4        2          10
```

after concatenation I get:

```
   Counter       Value
0        1           3
1        1           4
2        1           2
3        2           4
4        2          10
0        1           8
1        1          10
2        2           2
3        2           4
4        2          10
```

and I want to reset counter and make it sequential and make counter values to be by one digit bigger than the last group of counters.

```py
   Counter       Value
0        1           3
1        1           4
2        1           2
3        2           4
4        2          10
0        3           8
1        3          10
2        4           2
3        4           4
4        4          10
```

I was trying to shift all dataframe by one upwards and compare shifted values with original and if original one is bigger that the shifted one, add original value to all values below it. But this solution is not always working due to noisy and inconsistent raw data.

Comment: there wont always be difference of one number between two dataframes. I can add last rows value instead of one, but as I mentioned most of the time numbers that represent counter column are not even sequential in dataframe before concatenation

Comment: thats why i deleted it.. @yatu ans makes sense take the max and add before concatenating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the maximum value in the `Counter` column in the first dataframe to the second before concatenating:

```
df2.Counter += df1.Counter.max()
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

     Counter  Value
0        1      3
1        1      4
2        1      2
3        2      4
4        2     10
5        3      8
6        3     10
7        4      2
8        4      4
9        4     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another way using `shift()`:

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2])
df=df.assign(Counter_1=df.Counter.ne(df.Counter.shift()).cumsum())
#for same col df=df.assign(Counter=df.Counter.ne(df.Counter.shift()).cumsum())
```

---

```
   Counter  Value  Counter_1
0        1      3          1
1        1      4          1
2        1      2          1
3        2      4          2
4        2     10          2
0        1      8          3
1        1     10          3
2        2      2          4
3        2      4          4
4        2     10          4
```